# Calculating the timezone offset in a python format string

Tags: python, timezone

I have a datetime object that I need to convert to a given timezone and get the timezone offset at that date. Here's an example:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2045,11,30, 0,0,0).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
'2045-11-30T00:00:00'
```

I would like to dynamically add in the offset for the timezone "America/Chicago", so for example, the result would look like:

```
'2045-11-30T00:00:00T-06:00' # fluctuates based on DST, cannot be hardcoded
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Basically you need pytz or dateutil to accomplish your goals.  See the linked duplicate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.tzinfo). In the docs there is a working example of how it might work copied below:

```py
>>> from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
>>> class TZ(tzinfo):
...     """A time zone with an arbitrary, constant -06:39 offset."""
...     def utcoffset(self, dt):
...         return timedelta(hours=-6, minutes=-39)
...
>>> datetime(2002, 12, 25, tzinfo=TZ()).isoformat(' ')
'2002-12-25 00:00:00-06:39'
>>> datetime(2009, 11, 27, microsecond=100, tzinfo=TZ()).isoformat()
'2009-11-27T00:00:00.000100-06:39'
```

For your specific example the results look like:

```py
>>> datetime(2045,11,30, 0,0,0, tzinfo=TZ()).isoformat()
'2045-11-30T00:00:00-06:00'
```

If you want to calculate in the DST offset into that TZ offset, you'll need to use the [dst](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.tzinfo.dst) and there is a much longer example in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc) on implementing both of these together.

Comment: That has a hardcoded offset.  The OP specifically asked for how to do this with a named time zone whose offset fluctuates and thus cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint realized more what OP was asking after I originally answered which is why I edited in the bottom for how to do an offset based on DST and TZ together.